# Failed to obtain a generated Id with my programme. GWT

Tags: java, persistence, jdo

I am working on a client-server project in GWT and after the user fills a form, I would like to update my database and eventually create new datas.
For that, I create a "sensor" and the system link with which it is associated. But, the "sensor" is associated with a sensor Family too and I must create the link in my table sensorFamilySensorFamilyLink but I do not managed.
Indeed, here is my code for the creation of the sensor and the link:

```
     @Override
     public void updateSensor(SystemDTO system, SensorDTO sensorDTO, String sensorFamName) {

    Sensor sensor = null;
    SensorFamily sensorFam = null;

    if(sensorDTO.getId() <0) {
        sensor = new Sensor();
        sensor.fillFromDTO(sensorDTO);
        sensor.create();
    }
    else {
        sensor = Sensor.queryById(sensorDTO.getId());
        sensor.fillFromDTO(sensorDTO);
        sensor.update();
    }


    sensorFam = SensorFamily.queryByName(sensorFamName); 

    // Creation of the link between sensor and sensorFamily.

    SensorFamilySensorLink linksensor = null;
    if (!linkFam.isEmpty()) {
        linksensor = linkFam.get(0); // We take the first one because there is only one.
    }

    if(linksensor == null) { // creation of a sensor
        //List<SensorFamilySensorLink> liste = SensorFamilySensorLink.query();

        linksensor = new SensorFamilySensorLink();

        linksensor.setSensorId(sensor.getId());
        linksensor.setSensorFamilyId(sensorFam.getId());
        linksensor.create();
    }
    else {
        linksensor.setSensorFamilyId(sensorFam.getId());
        linksensor.update();
    }
```

Whereas the update works, the creation of the link does not work. Here is my code for the method "create":

```
   @PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION, detachable = "true")
   public class SensorFamilySensorLink {


/** The id. */
@PrimaryKey
@Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
private long id;

/** The associated sensor id. */
@Persistent
private long sensorId;

/** The associated sensorFamily id. */
@Persistent
private long sensorFamilyId;
    /**
 * Create.
 */
public void create() {
    PersistenceManager pm = PMF.getManager();
    Transaction tx = pm.currentTransaction();
    try {
        tx.begin();
        pm.makePersistent(this);
        tx.commit();
    } catch(Exception e) {

    } finally {
        if (tx.isActive()) {                            
            tx.rollback(); // Error occurred so rollback the PM transaction
        }
    }
    pm.close();
}
```

After debuggind, the problem comes from the generation if the IDs to use the SQL method INSERT in the table. THe generated id does not work when I am doing:

```
  pm.makePersistent(this);
```

Is someone can say to me what I have forgotten because I have been searching for two days and I do not how to solve the problem? Besides, I use the same code for creating the sensor link with the system and the family link and it is working for the first one.
If you need more information, do not hesitate to ask me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Define WHAT is "not working". You have a field "id" that will be AUTOGENERATE in the database (which database?), and it is not generated? what does the log say? Why are there "long" fields around? If they are relations to other persistable objects then those should be object references. Why does every field have @Persistent when all of those fields DEFAULT to persistent?

Comment: So was this user error?, bearing in mind you haven't come back and updated the post to clarify what you mean